# Change navigation controller title after a few seconds

Tags: ios

In an iOs app I am using a UINavigationController. On start-up this will have a title set but after a few seconds (in response to some data from a server) this title will need to change.

I tried:

```
self.title = @"new title";

self.navigationController.title = @"new";
self.navigationItem.title- @"new";
```

Nothing works... any suggestions?

Comment: self.title should do the trick. check if your getting a proper response and the request does not time out .. This is all i can think of right now..

Answer (score 2):

```
self.title = @"new";
```

This might set again after you have to got response from server in the method which is calling to get response.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Old title";

// after some time
double waitToUpdate = .5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(waitToUpdate * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    self.navigationItem.title = @"New title";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change `UINavigationController` title for each view is easy enough. you just need to change the value of `self.navigationItem.title`. If you wan't to change it with some delay, you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`. For example :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self performSelector:@selector(changeTitle:) withObject:@"New Title" afterDelay:2.]; // two seconds delay
}

- (void)changeTitle:(NSString *)title {
    self.navigationItem.title = title;
}
```